# How many would cost to mainain the raspberry pi powered on 365 days a year, 24hrs a day?

Tags: pi-4, power

Does someone know what would it be the medium cost on the electricity bill of having the raspberry pi 4 switched on on almost every moment of the year?

I have listened that the cost of the raspberry pi is very low, but I want to know a medium cost so I can make an idea

Actually, I'm running 2 python scripts, mysql, and apache.

Thanks a lot

Comment: We don't know how much you pay for electricity.  We don't know what you are powering from the Pi.  You need to do your own research.

Comment: That's why I say **medium cost**

Comment: Based on data coming from Texas in the U.S. I would guess somewhere between $10 and $1000 US.

Comment: It's roughly £1 per watt per year.

Comment: @Dougie - I get £3.41 per year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer requires only that you know your local energy costs, your RPi's rate of power consumption, and simple math.

#### Your local energy costs

Electrical energy costs vary considerably by season and by location. Since you didn't tell us where you live, we'll use [this source's estimate](https://www.hostdime.com/blog/average-cost-of-electricity-per-country/) of world average price of 0.14 U.S. Dollar per kWh for households.

#### Your RPi's rate of power consumption

Since you didn't tell us how much energy your RPi consumes, we can use the RPi Foundation's estimate of **600 mA** for ["Typical bare-board active current consumption"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md) for the RPi 4.

#### Simple math

In the dc case, electrical power ("**P**") consumption is the product of voltage, and current:

```
P = V * I
```

Energy ("**E**") is the product of power and time (or the integral/sum over time if power is not constant during the time period of interest):

```
E = P * T
```

And that leaves only the multiplication and conversion of units to obtain the annual Cost ("**C**"):

```
C = 5 volts * 0.6 amps * 24 hrs/day * 365 days/year * $0.14/kwh * .001 wh/kwh

C = US$ 3.68 per year
```

To put that in the form of a range of values based on [data from this source](https://www.hostdime.com/blog/average-cost-of-electricity-per-country/):

US$ 1.58/yr < C < US$ 9.20/yr

Comment: Thank you guys! You've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A power calculator below, a Pi on its own can only use `15W (3A x 5V)` maximum or `17.5W` with `3.5A` power supply like I have. Put them numbers in this with your electric rate, I got $54.31 when using the 24 hours a day for 20W at 31 cents (the default rate) a kw/h. Since my power rate is under half of that I am doing good, I allowed extra for the spinning hard drive and SSD attached to it to get the `20W` used. That would be all of those items running flat out maximum load, sitting like it does mostly idle it will be way under this worse case usage.

https://www.blitzresults.com/en/electricity/