# Raspberry Pi 4B power consumption headless with constant usage

Tags: pi-4, power

I'm setting up my Raspberry Pi 4b 2GB RAM in headless mode with a 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS Lite. It won't have anything plugged into it, but for an ethernet cable. It'll be performing FAH tasks (Dogecoin Folding At Home); however, I'm trying to find out how much energy it will use in this state (think maximum CPU usage is ideal). How much power will it use in, for example, a year?

Comment: [This answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/121512/83790) has calculations to answer your final question. Rpi power consumption is listed in [this table from the "official docs"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements). Due to the design of the RPi *closed-loop thermal management*, your system will use more energy if it is kept cooler - [this may explain](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130827/83790)

Comment: Ah, this *actually* answered my question for yearly power consumption. The other one didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Raspberry Pi Trading* (RPT) has [recommendations](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements) for various models which range from 700mA to 3.0A.

For the Pi4 "Typical bare-board active current consumption" is 600mA

https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/thermal-testing-raspberry-pi-4/
Shows comparison of Pi3B+ & Pi4.

Without anything connected to Raspberry Pi 4’s USB 3.0 ports and the latest firmware Raspberry Pi 4 draws 2.47W at idle and 6.79W running a worst-case synthetic load.

Only you can estimate the load of your application, but will be between 2.47W  and 6.79W

You ask "How much power will it use in … a year?" which is a meaningless question, but you could calculate the expected **Energy** consumption.